# php8.1-bcmath : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2) but 8.1.2-1ubuntu4 is to be installed

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am upgrading an image that used PHP 7.4 and now I am planning to use PHP 8.1.

However, I am getting the error

> php8.1-bcmath : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2) but 8.1.2-1ubuntu4 is to be installed
> php8.1-fpm : Depends: php8.1-common (= 8.1.2-1ubuntu2) but 8.1.2-1ubuntu4 is to be installed

On this line

```
apt install php8.1-bcmath php8.1-fpm php8.1-common
```

What I should do to install those dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved the issue by running the below command in sequence:

a. The below command will remove all the php packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
```

b. The below command will add the php repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

c. The below command will install all the latest php (in 2022, latest php package is 8.1) packages except for apache webserver packages.

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends php8.1
```

If you want to install all the apache webserver packages then run the above command *without* **--no-install-recommends**

Answer (score 6):

php8.1-bcmath needed php8.1-common compiled for Ubuntu version 8.1.2-1ubuntu2 but you have installed php8.1-common compiled for 8.1.2-1ubuntu4 (You have newest version).

Steps:

1. Remove php `sudo apt remove php8.1-common`
2. Install php with specific asked in error message ubuntu version `sudo apt install php8.1=8.1.2-1ubuntu2`
3. Install php extension fpm `sudo apt-get install php8.1-fpm`
4. Install php extension bcmath `sudo apt-get install php8.1-bcmath`

P.s. This solution work with any Ubuntu version - `sudo apt install php8.1=YOUR_VERSION_OF_ASKED_UBUNTU`

Comment: Don't do this on a production server. it will down the server!

Comment: I was do it in production and still works perfect

Comment: I've tried this but: `E: Version '8.1.2-1ubuntu2' for 'php8.1' was not found
`